# Determine who call stateChanged

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener, changelistener

I have a few sliders that look like this:

```
//Create the slider
    JSlider speedSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED, initValue);
    speedSlider.addChangeListener(controller);
    speedSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(MAJOR_TICK_SPACING);
    speedSlider.setPaintTicks(true);

    panel.add(speedSlider);
```

in my View.java class

there is Controller.java

```
public class Controller implements ControllerInterface {

    //...

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int speed = (int)source.getValue();
            if (0 == speed) {
                // stop
            }
            else {
                model.setSpeedBody(speed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not determine from what it was exactly the slider event, how to do it?
(ControllerInterface extends ChangeListener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the value of the source:

```
JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
if (source == speedSlider) {
    ...
}
else if (source == gearSlider) {
    ...
}
```

Or add a specific listener to each slider, so that each listener is notified of the changes of just one slider:

```
speedSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ...
    }
});
```